Azure FuncCoreTools won't open my Logic App designer because "Port 8000 is unavailable. Close the process using that port"
Problem
My Logic App Standard is not opening the designer because it says the Port its trying to use is unavailable.
I work on an AVD and I have multiple repositories with multiple apps. In one repository I can open the designer (I think there lies the problem: it doesnt close the port) but when I close VSCode etc. and want to open a logic app in another repository it gives the error "host start --port 8000" with pid: "20720"...
Port 8000 is unavailable. Close the process using that port, or specify another port using --port [-p]."
To clarify, this is the action im talking about:

Tried solutions that did not work
1.starting the func core tools with another port with a command like: "func host start --verbose  --port 10003"
This give me the following error: "Azure.Core: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. "
2.Closing the processes on the port
I used Resmon and "netstat -ano | find /i '8000'"  to identify the PID running on that port and using a "Taskill /F /PID <PIDNumber>" command
3.I closed the func.exe in task manager
4.Deleted the workspace file of the repo that was able to open the designer.
I really can't seem to kill the process on the port. I dont want to throw away my User Profile on the AVD to do this, so really anything to prevent that would help!

Do you have any active local software that "protects" your machine? I’ve had that and it was consistently the reason why.
